# How do we show that $x+\frac{i\log(\cos(ax))}{a}$ is equal to $\frac{i\log(1+e^{-2iax})}{a}$, or that they differ by a constant?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

How do we show that $x+\frac{i\log(\cos(ax))}{a}$ is equal to $\frac{i\log(1+e^{-2iax})}{a}$, or differ by a constant ?

I got these two different expressions while integrating $e^{-iax}\sec(ax)$, using Wolfram Alpha. Check [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20e%5E(-iax)sec(ax)) and [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(cos(ax)-i+sin(ax))%2Fcos(ax)).

Should I expand the second expression using the formula for $\log(1+x)$? I'm not very sure. Any hint will do.

Comment: Making black magics: it is false. Just substitute $\;x=0\;$ to get convinced...

Comment: @DonAntonio Maybe they differ by a constant? Did you check the Wolfram Alpha links I added?

Comment: Maybe they do. That part was added *after* I posted my comment. I don't usually check WA links: too many errors of that program in some basic things (though it is good "most" of the time to check stuff) and, above all, too may misprints in the askers' question to WA.  Anyway, yes: they could differe by a constant...but it is going to be a rather ugly one if we take into account the different result both expressions give when $\;x=0\;$ , say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\log(\cos(ax))=\log\left(\frac{e^{iax}+e^{-iax}}{2}\right)\\=\log(e^{iax}(1+e^{-2iax}))-\log2\\=\log(e^{iax})+\log(1+e^{-2iax})-\log 2\\=iax+\log(1+e^{-2iax})-\log 2$$